# Site showing up different on macs

Tags: html, css, browser

http://www.ab-mobile-apps.com/wp/absbm/

This site im working on is showing up fine in chrome and firefox on windows (tested on 3 computers). But the menu shows up wrong on macs in both chrome and firefox (tested on 3 computer). Does anyone know why this would happen?

Thanks

Comment: What's it look like on a Mac? How is it "wrong"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean that the background red image is not behind the entire menu. Try using the FireBug addon in both your Windows and Mac firefox to find out what you need to change to get both to work similar.
Also make sure you use the same (most recent) browser version for all platforms to eliminate bugs due to version differences.